# How to get mentioned user item object in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, mention

How to get mentioned user item object on button click. I am working with Ckeditor and wants to send email to all the mentioned user in my editor when I click on button send email. My issue is that I don't able to get all users which is mentioned when I click on button send email.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but on CKEditor v5, this can be achieved using the [range](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_range-Range.html) API.

Assuming one has the editor instance in variable named `editor`,

```js
// create a range spanning the whole document
const range = editor.model.createRangeIn(editor.model.document.getRoot());

const mentions = [];

//iterate through the whole tree in that range (TreeWalker)
for (const treeWalker of range.getWalker({ignoreElementEnd: true})) {
    
    if (treeWalker.type === 'text') {
        //the item property represents TextProxy which is not instance of node
        const node = treeWalker.item.textNode;

        if (node.hasAttribute('mention')) {
            const mention = node.getAttribute('mention');
            if (mention) {
                mentions.push(mention)
            }
        }
    }

}
```